# Rails 4 + Devise: Invalid route name, already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm following this how-to to modify the confirmation page after a successful sign up.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

I do everything like it says but i get this error:

```
in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

I guess the wiki is not updated for using Devise with Rails 4, but i don't find around enough information to fix the error.

The line which is returning the error is next (routes.rb):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

EDIT --

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    protected

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        '/sign_up/inactive'
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
root :to => 'home#index'
devise_for :users
resources :users

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Comment: I dare say you aren't doing 'exactly what it says'. Please show us your code.

Comment: I think you already has a simmilar duplicate conntroller which are already defined in Devise module

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have edited the main post with the content of my files, according what devise wiki says.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have two routes `devise_for :users` in your routes.rb - remove the first one.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice that little detail.