# Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' #Rails4 #Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Error message:

`ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
      You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`option, or you maybe overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.`

Here is my routes.rb

```
 root 'static_pages#launch'
 get "/demo" => "static_pages#home", via: "get"
 mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
 mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
 resources :contact_forms
 devise_for :users , controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
 match '/del_google_calendar_alert', to:'set_alerts#remove_google_calendar_alert', via: 'get'                        
 get "users/preferences"
 resources :events do #, shallow: true
  put :favorite, on: :member
    put :followfeed, on: :member
      put :share, on: :member
        put :submit, on: :member
 end

resources :campuses do
   resources :groups 
end
resources :users, except: [:create] do
 member do
   get :following, :followers
 end
end
resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

rake routes not showing an error in local machine but throwing an error when deployed in ec2 machine.

I tried with same versions of devise in both machines, still no success.

`rake routes` in my local machine

```
                 root GET      /                                              static_pages#launch
                 demo GET      /demo(.:format)                                static_pages#home
          rails_admin          /admin                                         RailsAdmin::Engine
             ckeditor          /ckeditor                                      Ckeditor::Engine
    letter_opener_web          /letter_opener                                 LetterOpenerWeb::Engine
        contact_forms GET      /contact_forms(.:format)                       contact_forms#index
                      POST     /contact_forms(.:format)                       contact_forms#create
     new_contact_form GET      /contact_forms/new(.:format)                   contact_forms#new
    edit_contact_form GET      /contact_forms/:id/edit(.:format)              contact_forms#edit
         contact_form GET      /contact_forms/:id(.:format)                   contact_forms#show
                      PATCH    /contact_forms/:id(.:format)                   contact_forms#update
                      PUT      /contact_forms/:id(.:format)                   contact_forms#update
                      DELETE   /contact_forms/:id(.:format)                   contact_forms#destroy
     new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
         user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)                users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter|linkedin|github|google_oauth2/}
user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)         users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter|linkedin|github|google_oauth2)
        user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
    new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                      PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                      PUT      /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
    user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                      PATCH    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                      PUT      /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                      DELETE   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
    user_confirmation POST     /users/confirmation(.:format)                  devise/confirmations#create
new_user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation/new(.:format)              devise/confirmations#new
                      GET      /users/confirmation(.:format)                  devise/confirmations#show
del_google_calendar_alert GET      /del_google_calendar_alert(.:format)           set_alerts#remove_google_calendar_alert
         del_fb_alert DELETE   /del_fb_alert(.:format)                        set_alerts#remove_fb_alert
         set_fb_alert GET      /set_fb_alert(.:format)                        set_alerts#set_fb_alert
set_google_calendar_alert GET      /set_google_calendar_alert(.:format)           set_alerts#set_google_calendar_alert
              refresh GET      /refresh(.:format)                             refresh#index
                delfb DELETE   /delfb(.:format)                               set_alerts#remove_fb_alert
                 sort GET      /sort(.:format)                                refresh#by_date
               search GET      /search(.:format)                              refresh#search
             myevents GET      /myevents(.:format)                            refresh#myevents
                 hall GET      /hall(.:format)                                refresh#hallevents
           all_campus GET      /all_campus(.:format)                          refresh#campusevents
            approvals GET      /approvals(.:format)                           admin#index
              approve GET      /approve(.:format)                             admin#update
    users_preferences GET      /users/preferences(.:format)                   users#preferences
       favorite_event PUT      /events/:id/favorite(.:format)                 events#favorite
     followfeed_event PUT      /events/:id/followfeed(.:format)               events#followfeed
          share_event PUT      /events/:id/share(.:format)                    events#share
         submit_event PUT      /events/:id/submit(.:format)                   events#submit
               events GET      /events(.:format)                              events#index
                      POST     /events(.:format)                              events#create
            new_event GET      /events/new(.:format)                          events#new
           edit_event GET      /events/:id/edit(.:format)                     events#edit
                event GET      /events/:id(.:format)                          events#show
                      PATCH    /events/:id(.:format)                          events#update
                      PUT      /events/:id(.:format)                          events#update
                      DELETE   /events/:id(.:format)                          events#destroy
        campus_groups GET      /campuses/:campus_id/groups(.:format)          groups#index
                      POST     /campuses/:campus_id/groups(.:format)          groups#create
     new_campus_group GET      /campuses/:campus_id/groups/new(.:format)      groups#new
    edit_campus_group GET      /campuses/:campus_id/groups/:id/edit(.:format) groups#edit
         campus_group GET      /campuses/:campus_id/groups/:id(.:format)      groups#show
                      PATCH    /campuses/:campus_id/groups/:id(.:format)      groups#update
                      PUT      /campuses/:campus_id/groups/:id(.:format)      groups#update
                      DELETE   /campuses/:campus_id/groups/:id(.:format)      groups#destroy
             campuses GET      /campuses(.:format)                            campuses#index
                      POST     /campuses(.:format)                            campuses#create
           new_campus GET      /campuses/new(.:format)                        campuses#new
          edit_campus GET      /campuses/:id/edit(.:format)                   campuses#edit
               campus GET      /campuses/:id(.:format)                        campuses#show
                      PATCH    /campuses/:id(.:format)                        campuses#update
                      PUT      /campuses/:id(.:format)                        campuses#update
                      DELETE   /campuses/:id(.:format)                        campuses#destroy
       following_user GET      /users/:id/following(.:format)                 users#following
       followers_user GET      /users/:id/followers(.:format)                 users#followers
                users GET      /users(.:format)                               users#index
             new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)                           users#new
            edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)                      users#edit
                 user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                           users#show
                      PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                           users#update
                      PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                           users#update
                      DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)                           users#destroy
           microposts POST     /microposts(.:format)                          microposts#create
            micropost DELETE   /microposts/:id(.:format)                      microposts#destroy
        relationships POST     /relationships(.:format)                       relationships#create
         relationship DELETE   /relationships/:id(.:format)                   relationships#destroy
                 help GET      /help(.:format)                                static_pages#help
           new_events GET      /new_events(.:format)                          static_pages#new_events
                about GET      /about(.:format)                               static_pages#about
              contact GET      /contact(.:format)                             static_pages#contact
                 team GET      /team(.:format)                                static_pages#team
                  faq GET      /faq(.:format)                                 static_pages#faq
            our_works GET      /our_works(.:format)                           static_pages#our_works
          patnerships GET      /patnerships(.:format)                         static_pages#patnerships`
```

I have checked out this post too but no success so far. [Rails 4 + Devise: Invalid route name, already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016761/rails-4-devise-invalid-route-name-already-in-use)

Update:

rake routes --trace helped me trace out the problem.

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `add_route'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1445:in `add_route'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1422:in `decomposed_match'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1420:in `block in decomposed_match'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1311:in `block (2 levels) in member'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:723:in `scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1310:in `block in member'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1540:in `with_scope_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1309:in `member'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1420:in `decomposed_match'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1403:in `block in match'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `match'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:601:in `map_method'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:562:in `get'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:347:in `block in devise_session'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1092:in `block in resource'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1549:in `block (2 levels) in resource_scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:723:in `scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1548:in `block in resource_scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1540:in `with_scope_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1547:in `resource_scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1091:in `resource'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:346:in `devise_session'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:236:in `block (4 levels) in devise_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:236:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:236:in `block (3 levels) in devise_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:441:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:338:in `block in devise_scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:840:in `block in constraints'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:723:in `scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:840:in `constraints'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:337:in `devise_scope'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:234:in `block in devise_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:217:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:217:in `devise_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google_authentication-0.3.0/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google_authentication-0.3.0/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/new_push/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Well, there are probably going to be issues due to overlap in routes generated by `devise_for :users` and `resources :users`, (e.g. `POST /users` would usually route to `registrations#create` for devise and `users#create` for your resources) but I wouldn't have thought that the routes would clash for `new_user_session` generally speaking (because devise routes `new_user_session GET /users/sign_in` to `sessions#new` which shouldn't clash with your resources).  What does `rake routes` show on your local machine?  And are you running different versions of rails locally and on ec2?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tim. I'm running rails 4.0.2 on both local and ec2 machines. I tried running rake routes with resources :users, except: [:create].No success. I'm updating the post with latest info.

Comment: That's strange. Was it the identical error msg (i.e. still complaining about `new_user_session`)? What happens if you temporarily comment out your `resources :users` and then perhaps your engine (railsadmin/ckeditor) mounts? If you still get the error, what if you comment out everything except the `devise_for` line? If the error doesn't then happen, you can gradually add the other routes back and see when the error starts being triggered again. If it does still happen with only `devise_for`, then that would be interesting! (BTW I tidied the routes by ensuring min. 4 chars at line start)

Comment: Same error with just `devise_for` in routes.rb. Crazy part is when i remove all routes even `devise_for` from routes.rb file, the error still persists. It says: `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'`. When i remove all routes in local machine, it says "you don't have any routes defined! Please add some routes in config/routes.rb". This is what it should show. Right?! How can this be possible? #headstratching

Comment: Finally, I got the solution. The problem is with google_authentication gem. Looks like version "0.3.0" is causing this error. I changed it to '0.2.0'. It worked like a charm. Rake routes --trace helped me circle out this. Now that the error is gone, let me recreate the error to post the trace :)

Comment: Excellent, glad you tracked it down!  Sorry I hadn't had a chance to respond to your last comments.  Sounds like you could now give an answer to this question and accept it to round off everything nicely.

Comment: Still have the issue with `users`, I only have one `devise_for` still error on `new_user_session`  already in use

Answer (score 2):

For further reference, the use of **"as"** option in devise_for may be handy.

```
devise_for :users , as: "unique_prefix", controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```