# problems using devise token auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I'm currently using Devise in my rails app. I want to add Devise Token Auth for authentication with my api . When I try to setup devise_token_auth with

```
rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth

rake db:migrate
```

I get following errors:

```
~/workspace (devise_token_auth) $ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:557:in `add_route'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1561:in `add_route'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1536:in `decomposed_match'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1534:in `block in decomposed_match'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1419:in `block (2 levels) in member'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1419:in `block in member'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1665:in `with_scope_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1415:in `member'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1534:in `decomposed_match'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1517:in `block in match'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1507:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1507:in `match'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:689:in `map_method'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:650:in `get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:374:in `block in devise_session'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1198:in `block in resource'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1676:in `block (2 levels) in resource_scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1676:in `block in resource_scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1665:in `with_scope_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1675:in `resource_scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1197:in `resource'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:373:in `devise_session'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:263:in `block (4 levels) in devise_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:263:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:263:in `block (3 levels) in devise_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:461:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:262:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:365:in `block in devise_scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `block in constraints'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `constraints'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:364:in `devise_scope'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:261:in `block in devise_for'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:237:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:237:in `devise_for'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)    '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)    '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher    '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)    '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main    '
Tasks: TOP =     db:migrate =     environment
```

I understand it is because of conflicts in routes.
How do i get it working ??
is there any workaround ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 + Devise: Invalid route name, already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016761/rails-4-devise-invalid-route-name-already-in-use)

Comment: @V-SHY nope it's a different question. It's solved :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use devise_token_auth along with devise we need to set a flag in devise_token_auth initializer as follows:

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  # enable_standard_devise_support = false
end
```

and route file needs to be changed as well

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # standard devise routes available at /users  
  # NOTE: make sure this comes first!!!

  devise_for :users

   # token auth routes available at /api/v1/auth
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end

end
```

I found this in [Devise Token Auth FAQs](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#faq)